# redirect loop with middleware in laravel 5

Tags: redirect, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

```
//Route.
Route::get('user/program', ['as' => 'chose.program', function(){
   dd('brake');
}]);
```

Middleware code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            $v = Opt::user_get('goal_chosen');
            if(!$v){
                return redirect()->route('chose.program')->with('warning', 'Please chose your program.');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Code in if statement cause to loop redirect. And 'brake' not show up;
Firefox browser say "The page isn't redirecting properly".

Can you guys help me out.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From your statement i could understand , you might placed the middleware for your mentioned route also. So cross check once . If you show your route file's middle applied section , can able to help you more on this case .

Comment: There is no other middleware on this route, at least I did not set up middleware on it. What exactly information can I provide?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to back request:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'Please chose your program.');
```

Comment: I need to redirect user on other page. 
And this example not working in my case anyway. Thanks.